# Which is faster asp.net mvc json or json.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I was wondering if anyone has run any benchmark tests on the JSON() function in Asp.net MVC and how it compares to JSON.NET? Also which one outputs the best json strings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a performance comparison [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/27/json-net-3-5-beta-1-big-performance-improvements-compact-framework-support-and-more.aspx). ASP.NET MVC uses the JavaScriptSerializer.

Json.NET gives you more control over outputting JSON (especially around dates) and also has the option for printing indented JSON.

Answer (score 2):

i am using the MVC json and it is a very good choice.
i used json.net in the past it was good but there is overhead because of the 3 party DLL 
asp.net 3 + is doing great with json.

give it a try ..

Comment: what performance overhead do you get from using a third party dll?

Comment: He did not say "performance" overhead, just an additional overhead of managing 1 extra dll, as opposed to something that is already present in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

An author of the [ServerStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) framework introduced a new [JSON serializer](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) for .NET and Mono, and their benchmarks quote higher performance than JSON.NET and WCF JSON Serializer.  At first glance it doesn't support a couple of important features from JSON.NET: indented serialized text, and it looks like it requires more code.